# Rails form inputs using context validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my app I have a validation rule like this

```
validates_presence_of :name, :on => :custom_context
```

When I'm saving my data I use

```
@obj.save(:context => :custom_context)
```

So that my context validation rule is applied. This works fine. By in my form, the name field is not marked with asterisk. How can I tell my form helper that we are in the `:custom_context` context and the name field must be marked as required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I guess there is no perfect way to do this. Eventually I did something like this:

```
<%= f.input :name, :required => required_in_context?(:name, :custom_context) %>
```

And I wrote a helper method:

```
def required_in_context? field, context
  required = false
  MyClass.validators.each do |v|
    required = true if v.kind == :presence && v.attributes.include?(field) && v.options == {:on => context}
  end
  required
end
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking the green tick next to it. It will mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you are trying to do BUT understood the scenario.
You can use an attribute_accessor  in your model say -

> attribute_accessor :context

In your view(.html.erb file) do the following inside your <% form_for %>

```
<%= f.hidden_field :context, :value => "custom_context" %>
```

And in your model :

> validates_presence_of :name, :if => Proc.new { |variable|
>   variable.context == "custom_context"}

I think this should help :D